# How to iterate through a dynamically created array in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle-jet

I have an array that is created from an API call.
Here is how I make this array-

```
var data5 = ko.observableArray(); /*Most important thing to make the data array observable otherwise it will not show the data of the REST API*/
var arrow = [];

function practiceData() {
  // var data = [];/**/

  $.getJSON("REST API").then(function(dataset) {
    $.each(dataset, function(index, value) {
      //console.table((dataset));
      //console.log(value.change);
      data5.push(value); // PUSH THE VALUES INSIDE THE ARRAY.
      arrow.push(value.change);
      console.log("arrow", arrow);
      arrow.forEach(function(value) {
        if (value == 0) {
          $("#triangle-down-small").hide();
          $("#triangle-up-small").hide();
          console.log("rgjak")
          console.log(value);
          //  document.getElementById("navTabBar").style.visibility = "none";
        } else if (value < 0) {
          //  $("#triangle-down-small").hide();
          $("#triangle-up-small").hide();
          console.log("hcdsb")
          console.log(value);
        }
      });
    });
  });
}
```

console.log(arrow)-

```
arrow (1) [0]
arrow (2) [0, 0]
arrow (3) [0, 0, -100]
```

JSON Response Structure-

```
[
{
        "change": 0,
        "count": 6,
        "duration": 4,
        "prevcount": 6,
        "subcategory": "Consultancy"
}
]
```

I am not able to iterate through the array as for the if-else condition the .hide() function works for just the if condition not for the else-if.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any console errors?  Also your broken up snippets are slightly confusing.  Is all that logic in the same place.  As in, is the second snippet a continuation of the `then()` call?

Comment: Also your first snippet does not clearly show what the json response structure is.

Comment: @ t.niese, The first snippet shows the console.log("arrow", arrow)

Comment: @Taplar, I have edited the snippets

Comment: The first snipplet is still unclear as to what your json response is.

Comment: What does the console show if you replace `console.log("arrow", arrow)` with `console.log('arrow', JSON.stringify(arrow, null, 2))`  and the  `arrow.forEach(function(value) { … });` with `arrow.forEach(function(value) { console.log(value, typeof value)});`

Comment: Ok, so the updated question with the bottom snippet, that's not an array.  That's just an object.

Comment: @Taplar, please check the JSON response Structure

Comment: And what is the error. You should always add the error message to yourpost

Comment: @t.niese, this is the output of the what you asked- `arrow [ 0], arrow [ 0,0], arrow [0,0,100]` and `0 "number", 0 "number", -100 "number"`

Comment: @RainerPlumer, There's no error message. The code just continues to run.

Comment: @Anonymous but if that's the output, then the loop you had before would log the corresponding `rgjak` and `hcdsb` outputs? If not then the code you show or your explanations, and the actual code you have won't match.

Comment: @t.niese, I have put my actual code in the question. Please check it.

Comment: @Anonymous The question is does `rgjak` and  `hcdsb` show up in the console or not for your code?

Answer (score 1):

Just for your reference, Move loop after $.each.  But no point of coding like this.Bad practice

```
function practiceData() {
  $.getJSON("REST API").then(function (dataset) {
    $.each(dataset, function (index, value) {
      data5.push(value); // PUSH THE VALUES INSIDE THE ARRAY.
      arrow.push(value.change);
    });
    console.log("arrow", arrow);
    arrow.forEach(function (value) {
      if (value == 0) {
        console.log("rgjak");
        console.log(value);
      } else if (value < 0) {
        console.log("hcdsb");
        console.log(value);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But the problem is still the same. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

The array foreach function is very simple and basic, so there is nothing wrong with that.
I guess your problem is that your data structure not being consistent or you have a logic problem in your code. 
You should make sure to always check that the values you push into the array exist and are numbers.

e.g

```
if (!value || typeof value.change === 'undefined') {
    return ;
}
```

Also, given your json response data, [0, 0, -100]
 both if and else statements will run and both buttons will be hidden.
 As long as there is one zero in your array, both buttons will be hidden.